Approaches to multiple pairwise comparisons following non-parametric 2-way ANOVA
We have a dataset with 3 treatments and 5 groups, with different $N$ for different combinations, with data that is not normally distributed.
We see significant effects using a Skillings–Mack Test across treatments, and are now searching for appropriate post-hoc tests.
One suggested approach was to use a Kruskall–Wallis Test across treatment and within each group, with Conover–Iman post-hoc, but I'm not sure this provides sufficient protection for the multiple comparisons.
I'm open to any suggestions, as well as potential alternatives to Skillings–Mack if there's a better approach there as well.

Hi Thomas, thank you for the edit, however I think Mack-Skillings is correct. The citation is Mack, G. A., & Skillings, J. H. (1980). A Friedman-Type Rank Test for Main Effects in a 2-Factor Anova. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 75(372), 947-951.
In our dataset we have a unbalanced incomplete block design, when the number of observations in each treatment/block pair is one or greater.
My understanding is that Skillings-Mack works when the number of observations is 0 or 1 for each treatment/block pair.

This is based on my reading of the Matlab implementations of both tests from Thomas Pingel at https://github.com/thomaspingel/mackskill-matlab and https://github.com/thomaspingel/skillmack-matlab

For anyone who comes across this, we settled on the Aligned Rank Transform, using the ARTool package in R. This can perform a full 2-way ANOVA with interaction tests and post-hoc contrast tests on non-parametric data, while controlling FWER.
See: https://github.com/mjskay/ARTool/
